# Get Firefox to reopen same file on disk (for testing)

Tags: firefox, geany, pandoc

I am writing documentation using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/), with a view to having it be viewed in HTML eventually on my web site. During development I want to test how the results look locally, so I have a build command set up in [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) like this:

```
pandoc --toc --smart --standalone %f -o %e.htm && firefox %e.htm
```

This all works fine, except that every time I hit the function key to run this, a new tab opens in Firefox, and eventually I have lots of them with older versions of my test document.

*My question ...*

Can I make Firefox reopen (or reload) a particular tab, from the command line?

---

Environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Firefox 39.0
- pandoc 1.13.2.1
- geany 1.23.1

Comment: Close the old tab when you are finished with it?

Comment: I'm not sure when I'm finished with it. I review the rendered output, change the markup, review, change etc. Finally I re-test. My point is that the "I'm finished with it" moment is not an easy decision to make. Sure, it's a couple of keystrokes to go back to the older tab and close it, but aren't computers supposed to save us effort? Having said that, certainly that is my current workflow. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should add a new Firefox profile, eg with the name `development`, for the following solution and start this profile (via `-P development`) for your development process.

With this profile open `about:config` and search for `browser.link.open_newwindow`.

Change the value to `1` to open links that would normally open in a new tab in the current tab.

<sub>[Source](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/03/force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab/)</sub>

Comment: Just to expand on this solution, which worked perfectly (thanks!) - I added `-P foo` to my command to open Firefox which opens the profile `foo`. With that profile open I did as suggested, and all seems to be well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use Firefox, you could also use the [WebHelper](http://plugins.geany.org/webhelper.html) plugin. It adds an minimal browser widget based on WebKit to Geany and can e.g. reload the page when saving the document. It's quiet handy on hacking CSS for a webapplication or other HTML related stuff.